# apex_web_service.parse_xml not parsing '& ' character

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, plsql

I am trying to parse the following SOAP response:

To do this I run an PL/SQL function:

```html
 l_xml := apex_web_service.make_request(
        p_url => 'http://eu-soaaut1-dv.abcdef.com/soa-
             infra/services/Sponsor/getProject',
         p_action => 'http://abcdef.com',
         p_envelope => l_envelope );

 l_result := apex_web_service.parse_xml(
            p_xml => l_xml,
            p_xpath => ' //tns:project',
            p_ns => ' xmlns:tns="http://abcdef.com"' );

    END;
```

And also I am trying to insert that parsed xml in one table with the following query:

```html
insert into dummy_web_services values(l_result);
```

As I am getting project details for some projects by giving their respective study numbers. But for some projects I am getting the following Error :

```
 ORA-31011: XML parsing failed 
 ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 21 
 LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use &amp;)
```

As per my understanding it is not parsing the '&' character which is there in my project detail data. Could anyone please suggest me how to overcome this problem.

Many thanks in Advance.

Comment: XML has some escape characters, you can replace all the `&` in your XML with `&amp;`, sometimes SQL clients dont allow that, so you can use `replace` `&` with `'&' || 'amp;'`

Comment: Can you check, where you are getting the error, is it while using `replace` or while `insert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'&' needs to be replaced anyhow, else XML parse will not work.

Store the XML object in a CLOB datatype variable, you can also store in VARCHAR2, if you know that data is less than 4000 characters, in that case use `getStringVal`

```
var_clob := l_xml.getClobVal;
```

Replace '&'

```
var_clob := replace(var_clob, '&', '&' || 'amp;')
```

Clob to XMLType again

```
l_xml := SYS.XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(var_clob);
```

`REPLACE` cannot be used on XMLTYPE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now I am able to get the Project Details for all projects.